# How can I create a contribution page that allows the user to select the currency they wish to use?

Tags: civicontribute, currency

CiviCRM provides the ability to have more than one currency "available". But when I set up a contribution page I have to select the currency that the page will use. If I want to give the user the choice of which currency to use to make their payment, do I have to create a different contribution page for each currency option, or is there a simple way of letting the user select their preferred option on the payment page itself?

Comment: Using multiple currencies within a single install is going to be potentially dangerous in a few ways. For example, you'll want to make sure your payment processor thinks it's processing in the same currency that the person filling out the form is thinking, or there might be some nasty surprises.

Comment: Thanks for this @alan-dixon. what I'm confused about is whether and how CiviCRM actually supports multiple currencies, beyond simply enabling the site administrator to have multiple currences available.

Comment: Well, "support" might be a stretch, but for example, contribution records have a currency field, so in theory the answer is yes, in the sense that it's imagined that it would be possible. If you're doing bookkeeping, you'll need to set up independent reports per currency, since currency conversion is definitely not in civicrm. One use-case that I'm pursuing now is an organization with separate US and Canadian incorporations, which I hope is not stretching the support too far.

Comment: Thanks Alan, that's really helpful. I'm about to begin testing to see what's workable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have an option of selecting multiple currency in the same page

So, Creating separate page of each currency could be a best option also easier way.

Or

You can create an extension for listing multiple currency in a single page, playing around price set  - which is going to take some time

Comment: I've found that having a different contribution page for each available currency seems to work reasonably well. To aid in reporting and analysis I've also set up a different financial type for each currency/contribution page. The payment processor I'm using - Stripe - looks to be working perfectly in passing the currency to Stripe's servers.